# Banshee with enabled ClutterFlow plugin crashes

Tags: banshee, plugins, clutter

Now I can't run Banshee, because of Banshee automatically quit after some time. 
*Question: Where is located banshee configs? Can i delete them to reset settings???*

Comment: have you tried the newest version of the plugin? it has shaders disabled and should work much better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Banshee config files are in /home/yourname/.config/banshee-1.
You can remove this folder to sre-enable default banshee config, but it will suppress your library, you will have to re-scan your disk once you launch Banshee.

Comment: Thx man :). Now Banshee runs correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than deleting all your banshee settings (and database) you can just clear your plugin settings by running

```
cp -R  ~/.config/banshee-1 ~/.config/banshee-1-backup
rm -rf ~/.config/banshee-1/addin-db-*
```

That also creates a backup... Just in case.

Answer (score 0):

~/.config/banshee-1/addin-db-001/config.xml

in the config.xml, edit the line with clutterflow in it to say 'false'.

I fixed the issue myself by just uninstalling clutterflow from Synaptic Package Manager, but I think editing the xml is probably a more elegant solution. I only just discovered the xml file now while trying to find a setting for the internet radio buffer.